# How to change all selected chars to _ in Vim

Tags: vim

I try to draw a class diagram using Vim.

- I fill the editor window with **white-spaces**.
- Type **:match SpellBad /\s/** to highlight all the white-spaces.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to select **vertical** white-spaces.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to insert **Bar(|)** and then <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- ...........................
- <kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> +... + <kbd>l</kbd> to select **horizontal** white-spaces

But I don't know how to change **all** selected horizontal white-spaces to **underscore(_)**.

I have to hit <kbd>_</kbd> serval times.
When comes to long horizontal line, it's bad.

```
  ___________             ___________               
 |           |           |           |              
 | BaseClass |/__________|  Client   |              
 |___________|\          |___________|              
      /_\                                           
       |                                            
       |____________________________________        
       |                 |                  |       
  _____|_____       _____|_____        _____|_____  
 |           |     |           |      |           | 
 | SubClass1 |     | SubClass2 |      | SubClass3 | 
 |___________|     |___________|      |■■■■■■■■■■■|
```

I want a quick method to do this.
**Select it -> Change it -> Done!**
Maybe map <kbd>F6</kbd> to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: If you know how many times you've got to hit '_' then you might as well hit `ni_` where `n` is the number of '_'s you want. Otherwise do what Amardeep has said.

Comment: Try out Dr Chip's [DrawIt](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=40) plugin. You can make a visual block selection, then invoke a command to draw a box around your selection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After everything you want to change is highlighted, type `r_`.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools for making ascii diagrams, and converting them to graphical UML. Why don't you try one of those?

e.g.

http://www.jave.de/

http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/

http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/studerende/firefly/stud.html